# How do I hide the red/pink pins that appear after searching?

Tags: google-maps

When I search for something in Google Maps, it puts a red/pink pin (or pointer/marker/icon) on the map for each search result in the viewport. Sometimes, these pins block my view of other things on the map that I want to see.

**How do I hide these pins from view?**

[image: screenshot of the red/pink pins]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mouse over the controls on the upper right of the map - it says satellite and possibly traffic. Other controls will roll out once you mouse over this area.

You'll see a control that allows you to remove the search result from the map by 'unchecking' next to the business name or search term.[image]